# Testnet mining greyed out

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mist, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm using Ethereum Wallet with Testnet Ropsten, and the blocks appear to be synced. The "Start Mining" option appears to be greyed out (same in Mist). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: same issue here