# Ethereum Wallet Start Mining option is disabled

Tags: mining, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I just downloaded Ethereum wallet and after syncing the blocks when I went to Start mining to get some Ether, the menu button is grayed out, its disabled

[image]

This is my wallet, in case if you can send me some Testnet Ethers

```
0x3cf387E565cb7466d2a334A6DeD2BBe3CA0242Eb
```

Comment: I can't mark it as such, but this appears to be a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21679/testnet-mining-greyed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first sync the full chain. Full steps on the link below.

[How to enable and mine Testnet (Morden)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-enable-and-mine-testnet-morden)

Comment: thats not applicable for Mist

Comment: I have been using this command on my windows system to mine and earn Ethers on testnet   ( geth --testnet --mine --minerthreads 1) . and you can so do.  I have transferred 200 ether to you.  Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the generosity :) I didn't knew about command line interface. Thanks again

Comment: I didnt receive the test Ethers. `0x3cf387E565cb7466d2a334A6DeD2BBe3CA0242Eb`

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED it with Mist.

1. GO TO `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth`
2. DELETE `chaindata` folder
   [image]
3. GO TO `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mist`

Delete content inside Cache folder

4. In the same folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mist`

Open file "**network**" with SublimeText editor, and  type: **ropsten** instead

SAVE.

5. Run Mist.exe "**Run as Administrator**"

Should sync and download some 14millions blocks and Mining should be enabled now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: . Please refer to screen print.]

The balance is already reduced from my account. Not sure why it has not reached your account

Comment: my testnet is set to Ropsten, does it matters ?