# I don't see "Start Mining" option?

Tags: mining, mist

I just installed Ethereum wallet, but I do not see the Start Mining option in the menu. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23924/ethereum-wallet-start-mining-option-is-disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see start mining option only in the private network... go to **develop**--> **network**-->**solo network** and now you will see start mining option. If you want to mine on the main network or test network you can do it by using Command line tools (geth) on your systems.

Thank you

Comment: But am I mining real ether in the solo network?

Comment: No, To mine real ether you can use command line tools to start the miner