# Start Mining with Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mist

Initially, the regular sync would not download the last 200+/- blocks or so. I was told to switch to light sync where it finished. I then read that to start mining real ether on the main network, I need to use geth here:

> [I don't see "Start Mining" option?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/i-dont-see-start-mining-option)

```
mist geth
```

After typing the command abolve into the terminal, I got the following:

[image: Terminal after typing mist geth]

My issue is, how do I know if I am mining ether or not? Or is there another step I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

when I am connecting mist to a private network I don't have the mining option neither. However, when I start mining from the geth javascript console, mist does indicate that my node is currently mining

[image: mist]

here is how I set things up (given that setting up a private network is still not straightforward in my opinion).

create a workspace:

```
$ mkdir devnet
$ cd devnet
devnet$ mkdir node1
```

create account for your mining node

```
devnet$ geth --datadir node1/ account new
```

save your address and password. Append `0x` to your address. Create a genesis file with puppeth (or just google for a simple genesis file)

```
devnet$ puppeth
```

now initialize your node

```
devnet$ geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json
```

start your node. Use same networkId as defined in genesis file (using puppeth)

```
devnet$ geth --datadir node1/ --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3" --networkid XXX
```

see [geth Command line options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for all commands.

connect a web3 javascript console to your geth node

```
devnet$ geth attach ipc:node1/geth.ipc
(or ~$ geth attach "http://localhost:8545")
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'password', 0)
> miner.start()
> exit // to quit the javascript console
```

or everything in one signle command

```
devnet$ geth --datadir node1/ --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3" --networkid XXX --unlock '0xaddress' --password passwords.txt --mine
```

connect mist to your node

```
devnet$ mist --rpc node1/geth.ipc
(or ~$ mist --rpc "http://localhost:8545")
```

here is the file structure for clarity:

```
devnet$ tree -L 2
.
├── genesis.json
├── node1
│   ├── geth
│   └── keystore
└── password.txt
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this is to mine real ether on the public network?

Comment: I am now also getting `ReferenceError: 'miner' is not defined` I have checked, my file structure is the same as yours except for `geth.ipc` in the node1 folder. I also could find a networkID in the genisis file so I used `0` as it is the first network I created.

Comment: 1) networkId **must** be defined in your genesis file.  Low values, are reserved to mainnet and public testnets: 1 is mainnet, 3 is rospten, 4 is rinkeby. Use something random like 3434.
2) pls spend some time on geth commands on options https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options
3) pls study the javascript JSON RPC API https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC
4) if you're using `networkId=1` then you're on the mainnet and mining real ether (but in that case you don't need a genesis file as those values are predefined in geth source code). you can do it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a private network.
Try to open a second terminal and type

geth attach

You will see the JavaScript console, then try   miner.start(1)

Comment: Reading in the console, it has now confirmed that the network is mainnet after using geth attach. However no js console opened. just mist.